# Flutter : onPressed for imagepicker function not working

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I built an image picker after learning in a course. I am not getting any errors in the debug console or in the build. I am trying to click it but it is not working. I made another image picker in a similar manner in same app but that did not gave any error

My add image screen:

```
class _AddImageState extends State<AddImage> {
  bool uploading = false;
  double val = 0;
  CollectionReference? imgRef;
  firebase_storage.Reference? ref; 

  List<File> _image = []; 
  final picker = ImagePicker();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Add Image'),
        actions: [
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                uploading = true;
              });
              
              uploadFile().whenComplete(() => Navigator.of(context).pop());
            },
            child: Text(
              'Upload',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Stack(children: [
        GridView.builder(
            itemCount: _image.length + 1,
            gridDelegate:
                SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(maxCrossAxisExtent: 1),
            itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
              return i == 0
                  ? Center(
                      child: IconButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            !uploading ? chooseImage() : null;
                          },
                          icon: Icon(Icons.add)),
                    )
                  : Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(3),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          image:
                              DecorationImage(image: FileImage(_image[i - 1]))),
                    );
            }),
        uploading
            ? Center(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                        child: Text('uploading...',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20))),
                    CircularProgressIndicator.adaptive(
                      
                      value: val,
                      valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.green),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              )
            : Container()
      ]),
    );
  }
```

choose image function :

```
chooseImage() async {
    
    final pickedFile = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    setState(() {
      _image.add(File(pickedFile!.path));
    });
    if (pickedFile!.path == null) retrieveLostData();
  }
```

I tried onPressed:  chooseImage; but it still did not work

Answer (score 0):

Try to slighlty altering your image picker function ike this-

```
chooseImage() async {
    ImagePicker picker= ImagePicker();

    pickedFile = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    setState(() {
      _image.add(File(pickedFile!.path));
    });
    if (pickedFile!.path == null) retrieveLostData();
  }
```

Why is `file` a final variable? And make sure this function is inside your _addImageState or setState() wont function. If any of these dont work, it's prolly a permission problem

Edits-

If you definitely don't want this in your __addImageState()- Try doing this-

```
Future<Uint8List> chooseImage(ImageSource source) async {
  ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();
  file? file = await picker.pickImage(source: source);
  return file;
}
```

And where you are calling it, do

```
file= await chooseImage();
if (pickedFile!=null){
setState((){
 _image.add(File(pickedFile!.path));
});
}
```

Comment: If I am removing final it is showing "picked file is undefined".  For the second one it is giving error - "The name 'Uint8List' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument.
Try correcting the name to an existing type, or defining a type named 'Uint8List'." I think onpressed has some issue

Comment: No, it's most probably not an issue with onpressed. Did you try putting the function in the __AddImageState class? SetState won't function otherwise.